# Highcharts two date compare

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a chart with two graphs. One last week and another this week.

```
$('.js-hostChart-'+chart).highcharts
      chart: { type: 'area' }
      title: null
      xAxis:
        type: 'datetime'
        tickInterval: 3600000*2
        title: null
      yAxis:
        title: null
      tooltip:
        shared: true
        crosshairs: true
```

As can be compared to two weeks in a line?

Answer (score 2):

Depends what you mean exactly.

If you mean you want to compare this week/last week, sharing the same x axis values, then you'll need to tweak your data.

There are several ways you can go about this:

1) drop the datetime axis, and use either categories (one per day, or hour, or whatever your increment is). This way for each data point you just specify the category index as the x value, instead of a date

2) if you want to maintain the datetime axis type, for whatever reason, you will need to modify the dates of the 'off' week, so that they match the dates of the current week. Then you will need to modify your tooltip and other formatters to properly display the correct date to the user

3) You could get complicated by using multiple x axes, and assign each week to a different axis.